# Better ways of sorting NSArray in Objective - C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, sorting

G'Day Everyone,

Recently I have started learning iOS development. I initiated my learning process by learning Objective C language. Before I am proficient in Java, In natural computer sense "Java is my first language".

Because of that I am having lots of difficulty when I see really long methods in Obj - C, Which meant to do really easy things. Let me share some codes which are very long just to sort NSArray content Ascending order and Descending order (Alphabetically)

**Sort NSArray in Ascending order A - Z**

---

```
[dataToShow sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]; // dataToShow is my NSArray
```

**Sort NSArray in Descending order Z - A**

---

```
NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil ascending:NO selector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];
[dataToShow sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]; // dataToShow is my NSArray
```

Now is there any better way, By better way I mean shorter way of achieving same result? As I am naive, I would like to know if there is any other method which might be as long as above one but does sorting in more better ways.

Thank you

Comment: are you trying to figure out how t do it with shorter code or shorter processing time?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. The code you have supplied looks use fine to me. I've been in the Java world for many years and Objective C for the last 2 and these examples look just fine to me.

Comment: just one comment: the `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:` uses the current locale to do the proper sorting, sometimes achieving "odd" results if you are expecting ASCII order.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to make it clear. What I was looking for is a shorter in code. However answers I got from omz is good enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get used to it. It's common and even desirable in Objective-C to have long, descriptive method names. Of course you could wrap things that you do very often in your own methods or macros, but I wouldn't deviate too much from the Cocoa naming style as it makes your code harder to read for others.

See the [Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-BBCHBFAH) for some background.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you get comfortable with [blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html).

```
NSArray* sortedArray =[array sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id thing1, id thing2) 
{ 
    /* return NSComparisonResult following conventions of strcmp */ 
}];
```

It doesn't get much easier than that